# RangeSlider.js is not working when i call from another js page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rangeslider

```
$element.rangeslider({

    // Deactivate the feature detection
    polyfill: false,

    // Callback function
    onInit: function() {
        valueOutput(this.$element[0]);
    },

    // Callback function
    onSlide: function(position, value) {
        console.log('onSlide');
        console.log('position: ' + position, 'value: ' + value);
    },

    // Callback function
    onSlideEnd: function(position, value) {
        console.log('onSlideEnd');
        console.log('position: ' + position, 'value: ' + value);
    }
});
```

i have called external rangeslider.js page also but still it saying  $element.rangeslider is not defined.

Comment: Have you definitely included the rangeslider code to be loaded BEFORE it's called - can you show more code where you are including the script?

Comment: i append my script like this -- $("head").append($("<script type='text/javascript' src='../../widgets/rangeslider.js'>"));

Comment: when i console the page in network tab where all files loaded its shows rangeslider.js is loaded as xhr not as script! . I don't know why?                                                                   Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to load the script using getScript.

Comment: You are not loading the script twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution, where you will be waiting for the script to be loaded then calling your desired functionality.

```
$.getScript( "YourJS.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
         console.log( textStatus );
          //Preform here
        }) ;
```

The working example.

```js
init(1,10);
function init(min,max){
   $("#io").append($("<div style='text-align:center;'><div><input type='range' id='slider' min='" + min + "' max='" + max + "' step='1' value='3' data-rangeslider><output id='val'></output></div></div>"));
    $('head').append('<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.2/rangeslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
   $.getScript( "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.2/rangeslider.js" )
       .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
         console.log( textStatus );
          //Preform here
          initRangeSlider($("#slider"));
        }) ;
}

function initRangeSlider(ele){
   ele.rangeslider({

    // Deactivate the feature detection
    polyfill: false,

    // Callback function
    onInit: function() {
        //valueOutput(this.$element[0]);
    },

    // Callback function
    onSlide: function(position, value) {
        console.log('onSlide');
        console.log('position: ' + position, 'value: ' + value);
    },

    // Callback function
    onSlideEnd: function(position, value) {
        console.log('onSlideEnd');
        console.log('position: ' + position, 'value: ' + value);
    }
   });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='io'></div>
```

Comment: my js file loaded but still same error $element.rangeslider is not defined

Comment: There can be two causes which may be creating this bug. 1. Are you calling the script after the script loaded? 2. You might be loading the script in the parent instead of your iFrame.

Comment: This is my div $(this).append($("<div style='text-align:center;'><div><input type='range' id='slider' min='" + min + "' max='" + max + "' step='1' value='3' data-rangeslider><output id='val'></output></div></div>"));  after this im calling my script.